# How to connect Dial-up connection automatically in WINCE7 for colibri T20

Tags: windows, batch-file, application-settings, modem, controlpanel

I am newbie to `Colibri boards`. I am using `WINCE7` in my `colibri T20 board`. In this board every time I connect `my modem` via `USB`, I have to make settings in `Networks and Dial-up connections`. I want to make the connection automatically on `start-up`. For this I can make settings using `registry file` but Still I need to open `my connections` in `Networks and Dial-up connections` and click `connect` button. I can't figure out how to automate this thing. So, please help me to automate my modem connections. Thanks